# subform record overwriting

Tags: ms-access, header, report, footer

I'm setting up a student database,

I have a class assignment form to add the block (semester), period and class name which i can then view in a query subform at the bottom of my form.

My class assignment table is set out like this:

{ClassAssignID,
StudentID,
BlockID,
Period,
OptionID}

There are 4 classes to be chosen per block.
I can add one record per block, but my problem is when i try to add a second class it just overwrites the first so it can only hold one class.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are sure that this is what is happening? That is, you have looked at the table? What is the record source of your subform? Did you create it using the wizards?

Comment: i've checked the tables my subform is based on and there's only one record.
The subform is based on a query to show {student ID, Block, Period, Option Name, Class, Tutor}

Comment: Generally when someone says 'what is the rows source?' they mean cut and paste sql. Did you use the wizards to create the subform?

Comment: Apologies
       

 `SELECT TblPersonalInfo.Student_ID, tblBlock.Block,     tblClassAssignments.Period, tblOptions.Option_Name, tblOptions.Room, tblOptions.Tutor
FROM TblPersonalInfo INNER JOIN (tblOptions INNER JOIN (tblBlock INNER JOIN tblClassAssignments ON tblBlock.Block_ID = tblClassAssignments.Block_ID) ON tblOptions.Options_ID = tblClassAssignments.Option_ID) ON TblPersonalInfo.Student_ID = tblClassAssignments.Student_ID;`

No i add the subform manually

Comment: That looks far too complicated for a subform. Subforms generally use fairly simple sql with link child / master fields and combo boxes to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Where would i find the wizard to create a simpler subform?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15168/discussion-between-remou-and-sawyer05)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, the sql for a subform should be fairly simple, extra information can be obtained from comboboxes and link child and master fields.

In this case, there was also a problem with indexes, as was revealed by chat. A combination of restrictive indexes and relationships prevented data from being added to the table.